# Can you set the entire "this" keyword to an object in the constructor of a class for Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service that gets json user data, I want to add some methods onto the object. I was thinking of doing this by having a class for user data, and passing the object i get from the json into my constructor like so:

```
class UserData {
  constructor(userData){
    this = userData
  }

  getNode1(){
    return this.textNodes.node1;
  }
}
```

in my service I have code like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserData } from 'wherever';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserDataService {
  userData;

  constructor() { 
    let backendData = {
      textNodes: {
        node1: "some text",
        node2: "some other text"
      }
    }

    this.userData = new UserData(backendData);
  }
}
```

I tried but got This error: Module parse failed: Assigning to rvalue.

I could just do the whole object and every field likes so: `this.textNodes.node1 = backendData.textNodes.node1` for every single field, but it's a huge ugly object.

Does anyone have a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `this` equal to anything inside the class will never ever work. `this` is the reference to the class you are currently in, so you would dismiss the reference to itself then. You could try something like this:

```
class UserData {
  private userData: UserDataInterface;
  constructor(userData: UserDataInterface){
    this.userData = userData
  }

  getNode1(){
    return this.userData.textNodes.node1;
  }
}

interface UserDataInterface {
  textNodes: {
    node1: any;
    node2: any
  };
}
```

Comment: Alternatively `userData` could be merged into `this` with `Object.assign(this, userData)`

Comment: Thanks acincognito, it works but requires restructuring. Thanks UncleDave, that's exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see here, you have 2 easy solutions:

1- Use Object.assign function.

```
this.userData = Object.assign(new UserData(), backendData);
```

2- If your data is coming from an http request and you're using HttpClient, just do something like

```
this.http.get<UserData>(backendUrl)... etc
```

If will deserialize it automaticaly for you.

I hope I've been helpful.